# .ready() method of jQuery for handling spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, ready

I am trying to have a spinner shown while div's background image is loading:

```
    var div = $("<div class='spinner' id="+this.room.views[this.currentIndex].domID+"></div>");
        div.css('background-image', 'url(img/spinner.gif)');
        div.appendTo('#scene');
        var background = new Image();
        background.src = room.views[this.currentIndex].background;
        background.ready(function(){
            div.removeClass('spinner').addClass('view');
            div.css('background-image', 'url('+background.src+')');
        });
```

It is throwing an error: "Uncaught TypeError: background.ready is not a function"

I checked similar questions re spinners, but I am not sure I understand the answers :(

The idea is that I show .gif spinner by default until the image is loaded and then replace the spinner by adjusting .css

I hope that someone will be able to explain step by step what needs to be done.

P.S. I tried div.onload = function() { ...}(); but it did not work too.

Comment: you forgot to wrap background with jQuery $(background).ready

Comment: @Saar It will not change anything. ready makes sense only for `document`.

Comment: So, what should be the way to move forward here?

Comment: I would think `background.on('load', function() {`.

Answer (score 0):

And as always answering own questions :)

Since .load() is deprecated, using .on('load', function(){})

```
        $(background).on('load', function(){
            //do stuff;
        });
```